# Box characters in VSCode terminal instead of letters

Tags: visual-studio-code

In Manjaro Linux, Instead of displaying the full path of my workspace in the terminal, it shows these box characters. How do I fix this?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

changed the `Default Profile` of the terminal to `bash` and then changed the `Terminal: Explorer kind` option to `external`

Answer (score 0):

I've fixed mine via the JSON configurations, e.g.:

```json
"terminal.integrated.fontFamily": "JetBrainsMono Nerd Font",
```

Just to be sure, try matching the same font you have on your default terminal emulator.